# How do I unlock a content control using the OpenXML SDK in a Word 2010 document?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am manipulating a Word 2010 document on the server-side and some of the content controls in the document have the following Locking properties checked

- Content control cannot be deleted
- Contents cannot be edited

Can anyone advise set these Locking options to false or remove then altogether using the OpenXML SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The openxml SDK provides the `Lock` class and the `LockingValues` enumeration
for programmatically setting the options:

- Content control cannot be deleted and
- Contents cannot be edited

So, to set those two options to "false" (`LockingValues.Unlocked`), 
search for all `SdtElement` elements in the document and set the `Val` property to
`LockingValues.Unlocked`.

The code below shows an example:

```
static void UnlockAllSdtContentElements()
{
  using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =
    WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"c:\temp\myword.docx", true))
  {        
    IEnumerable<SdtElement> elements = 
      wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<SdtElement>();

    foreach (SdtElement elem in elements)
    {
      if (elem.SdtProperties != null)
      {
        Lock l = elem.SdtProperties.ChildElements.First<Lock>();

        if (l == null)
        {              
          continue;
        }

        if (l.Val == LockingValues.SdtContentLocked)
        {
          Console.Out.WriteLine("Unlock content element...");
          l.Val = LockingValues.Unlocked;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  UnlockAllSdtContentElements();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the ones who copy this code, keep in mind that if there is no Locks associated to the content control, then there won't be a Lock property associated to it, so when the code executes the following instruction, it will return a exception since there is no element found:

```
Lock l = elem.SdtProperties.ChildElements.First<Lock>();
```

The way to fix this is do the `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`.

Comment: Should be added as a comment to relevant solution

Comment: Hi @OriPrice, i cannot comment the solution since my reputation is below 50. Regards.